# LSTM + Nvidia GPU causes NotImplementedError

Tags: python-3.x, lstm, tensorflow2.0

I have Python 3.9.7, TensowFlow == 2.5, NVIDIA-SMI 497.09, Driver Version: 497.09, CUDA Version: 11.5. On trying to define a LSTM model as follows:

```
n_steps = 500
n_features = 1

# Univariate multi-step time series prediction-
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(units=50, activation='relu', return_sequences=True, input_shape=(n_steps, n_features)))
```

It first gives a warning:

> WARNING:tensorflow:Layer lstm_4 will not use cuDNN kernels since it
> doesn't meet the criteria. It will use a generic GPU kernel as
> fallback when running on GPU.

And then:

> NotImplementedError: Cannot convert a symbolic Tensor
> (lstm_4/strided_slice:0) to a numpy array. This error may indicate
> that you're trying to pass a Tensor to a NumPy call, which is not
> supported

Changing the activation to 'tanh' doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your numpy version. Is it above 1.20? Here's [issue #14687](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/14687) with the same problem, and they point to [issue #47691](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/14687), where they fixed this in tensorflow 2.6.

So, either downgrade to numpy 1.19.2, `pip install numpy==1.19.2` or upgrade tensorflow, `pip install --upgrade tensorflow`. This should hopefully fix the issue!